# Execute jquery after changing classes "active"

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using symphony and I have a tab system like this :

```
<div class="logs">
    <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="list active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">PDF</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Crawl</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">EAN/cats</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content tab-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-flat affichage">Résumé</button></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-flat affichage">Complet</button></div>
                <div class="col-md-8"><span class="log"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content tab-body">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">

            <div class="resum"></div>
            <div class="compl"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">

            <div class="resum"></div>
            <div class="compl"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">

            <div class="resum"></div>
            <div class="compl"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With js, when I click on a tab, there is a system of active class that allows content to be displayed (I'm using bootstrap)

My problem is that I have some jquery code that is executed before the active class are put on the correct div

```
$('.affichage').click(function()
{
    if (! $('.tab-content .active .compl').hasClass('done') || ! $('.tab-content .active .resum').hasClass('done'))
    {
        affichage( $(this).text() );
    }

    if ($(this).text() == "Résumé") 
    {
        $('.tab-content .active .compl').addClass('hide');
        $('.tab-content .active .resum').removeClass('hide');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.tab-content .active .resum').addClass('hide');
        $('.tab-content .active .compl').removeClass('hide');
    }

});

$('.list').click(function()
{
    if (! $('.tab-content .active .resum').hasClass('done'))
    {
        affichage( "Résumé" );
    }

    $('.tab-content .active .compl').addClass('hide');
    $('.tab-content .active .resum').removeClass('hide');

});
```

What I want to know is if there's a way to execute my code after the active class are changed

cheers

Comment: Which code is executed before the class is put on?  Why can't you just place that code after the class is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mohit Kumar, but you code was incomplete (it set me on the right way though)

here's the code :

```
    $('.list').click(function()
{
    $(".list").removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
    var index = $(this).find('a').attr('href').substring(1);
    console.log(index);
    $(".tab-pane").removeClass('active'); 
    $('#'+index).addClass('active');

    if (! $('.tab-content .active .resum').hasClass('done'))
    {
        affichage( "Résumé" );
    }

    $('.tab-content .active .compl').addClass('hide');
    $('.tab-content .active .resum').removeClass('hide');

});
```

It changes the active class in the tabs & in the div that has the content that I want to show, this last part was what was missing in your code.

thanks anyway, I will mark yours as the answer as soon as you edit your answer so it fits the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav li").click(function(){
        $(".nav li").removeClass('active'); //it will remove active class from all elements.
        $(this).addClass('active'); //this will activate active class on clicked element

     setTimeout(function() {
        //your code which you want to execute after active class.
    }, 5000); 

    });
});
```

> in this process
>
> 1. active class will removed
> 2. than active class will be appended on clicked element.
> 3. here we used Timeout function which will execute your rest of code after 5 seconds.

Comment: why do you need a settimeout? if you place the code after the addClass, it will be executed after the class is added

Comment: change your answer with what I have & I will mark yours as the answer ^^